# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : one node produced an error: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, database, dataframe, rscript

in my code

```
if(nrow(data[]) == 0) ####gives **output 0** where as 
if(length(data[] == 0) #### gives **output 2** its counts maybe the row heading
```

so in order to be inside if I need 0 and I use **nrow** for that as it satisfies my condition

```
if(nrow(data[]) == 0)
```

which throws error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  one node produced an error: argument is of length zero
```

for other cases

Comment: Also output for length(data[]) is <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) instead of Dataframe with 0 columns and 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a data frame with no rows and no columns, such as this:

```r
data <- data.frame()

data
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

And if you count the rows using `nrow` you will get zero without any problem:

```r
if(nrow(data[]) == 0) cat("Zero row data frame!")
#> Zero row data frame!
```

But in your case, it seems that there *is no data frame called data*. If we make `data` NULL, then we can reproduce your error:

```
data <- NULL
if(nrow(data[]) == 0) cat("Zero row data frame!")

#> Error in if (nrow(data[]) == 0) cat("Zero row data frame!"): argument is of length zero
```

One way round this is to ensure that your data frame actually exists before testing how many rows it has:

```r
data <- NULL

if (!is.null(data)){
  if(nrow(data[]) == 0) cat("Zero row data frame!")
} else {
  cat("Data frame does not exist!")
}
#> Data frame does not exist!
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @user16656588 - that sounds like a different problem from the one you asked about. Please edit your question to include all relevant information, rather than adding more complex information in the comments. Thanks

Comment: Okay lets stick to the above question.
in addition it

Comment: I want that nrow(data[]==0) gives me same answer as length(data[]==0)

also for verion 3.5.1 I was using length(data[]==0) and it was working just fine but now after the version change to R 4.1.1

I see that for length(data[]==0 which earlier gave me True and data contained No of rows and cols are 0.

the same line of code gives me length(data[]==0 value False and data has a number 2 in it and when I print data it says 

<0 rows > (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: I just want this length function to work fine here so there is no need to use nrow at all. and I can use my previous code

Comment: Thanks!! @Allan Cameron.
it works just fine by declaring null into it prior. Thanks!!